# I want to echo something only on the first time foreach runs

Tags: php

I want to echo something only on the first time foreach() runs!
let's say if I have an array $i

```
$i = array(............);
```

and I want to use it in foreach like...

```
foreach($i as $key => $value) {
  echo '<h1>'.$key.'</h1>';
  echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
}
```

while this foreach runs the first time only i want to add *class="show"* to the h1 tag.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update code:

```
$i=['hello','world'];
foreach($i as $key => $value) {
     $class= ($key == 0)?'show':'';
      echo '<h1 class="'.$class.'">'.$key.'</h1>';
      echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';

}
```

Output:

```html
<div>
        <h1 class="show">0</h1><p>hello</p>
         <h1 class="">1</h1><p>world</p> 
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a var to track that

```
$first = 0;
foreach($i as $key => $value) {
  $show=($first == 0) ? 'h1 class=show' : 'h1';
  echo '<$show>'.$key.'</h1>';
  echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
  $first++;
}
```

There are many ways to do it, but this might be easier to read

Answer (score 0):

if you have single dimension array then you can use

```
$i=['test1','test2','test3'];

     foreach($i as $key => $value) {
         if($key == 0){
            echo $key;
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
         }
    }
```

if you have an associative array

```
$i=array('a'=>'test1','b'=>'test2','c'=>'test3');
        $j = 0;
     foreach($i as $key => $value) {
         if($j == 0){
            echo $key;
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
         }
         $j++;
    }
```

output will be